# Tomcat won't run even though i already downloaded a copy of jdk

Tags: tomcat

Hello im having trouble with xampp, apache and mysql are fine but when i click the start button for tomcat, a command prompt appears  entitled c:\xampp\catalina_start.bat which says it is not recognized as an internal or external operable program or batch file and wont run tomcat. How do i solve this? I already downloaded a copy of jdk

Comment: when you in c:\xampp execute `java -version` what's the output. What's the output when you run `c:\xampp\catalina_start.bat`?

Comment: Adding stack trace or log would be helpful.

Comment: When i run the c:\xampp\catalina_start.bat it would just let me press any key and nothing happens